# how to combine the column from 2 different xml file in one xml file in pentaho

Tags: xml, pentaho-data-integration

Friends i have 2 get xml data function to get data from 2 different xml containing same number of rows. Now, i want to combine the column from file1 to file 2 or vice versa or even combining all column in a different file. I have tried many ways but i couldn't get it. Any suggestion is accepted even if both file has same column names.

Note: Both xml file will have same number of rows

[first file preview data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD6g1.png)

[second file preview data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMKCE.png)

Comment: guys I found the solution, just get the xml data through a "text file input" step which will get the input in row instead of getting in differnt column and then pass this input to a java script where we can do some modification in code if we want and then write it using the text file output with .xml extension

Comment: Generally, processing XML documents as simple text is a bad idea.  If you can't describe a problem properly, it sometimes helps to provide the desired outcome.

Comment: marabu here i'm just going to display a merged two xml file as output nothing more